# REplace issue in livecode

Tags: livecode

How to overcome the issue relating this replaces.
I need to replace " snn" with "" & " sss" & "" in myHtml. 
it will replace all " snn" with " sss". but it will not work in the begin of a line(newline, \n).

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Comment: This is only an example : I want to change " the " with " an ". it will not replace " the "  if the "the" is in the begining of text.

Comment: I have answered your question. Please, vote it up AND accept the answer if it is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume we have the following data

> the man stands on the floor
>   The man etc

in field 1. We can replace any occurrence of `the` or `The` or `space & the` or `linefeed & the` with `an` using the following syntax

```
on mouseUp
     put word 1 to -1 of replaceText(space & fld 1,"[\n ][tT]he "," an ") 
end mouseUp
```

Note the extra preceding space, which is removed again using `word 1 to -1`.

Unfortunately, this syntax replaces linefeeds with spaces. Id on't know if you want this. If not, I'd suggest using two lines, one for space and one for linefeed.

```
on mouseUp
     put replaceText(space & fld 1,"[\n]([tT]he) ",cr & "an ") into myTempVar
     put word 1 to -1 of replaceText(myTempVar,"[ ]([tT]he) "," an ")
end mouseUp
```

It seems a little strange to me to always replace "the" with "an" but it does what you're asking for.

Comment: I have answered your question. Please, vote it up AND accept the answer if it is useful. That will motivate me to also answer your next question about colourizing text.

Comment: Oh! sorry Mark. You did a very good job. Really appreciable for your quick response.

Comment: Thanks. It is good to know when an answer is helpful (or even if it isn't).